# Цикл retrofit-запросов из AsyncTask в RxJava

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rxjava, retrofit2

Как можно переделать следующий код из AsyncTask (из метода `doInBackground`) в RxJava?

```
MessageRq rq = new MessageRq();
rq.setId(id);
Call<MessageRs> response = App.getApi().getFirstCommand(rq);
nextLink = getNextUrl(response, rq);
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {   
    response = App.getApi().authorize(nextLink, rq);
    nextLink = getNextUrl(response, rq);
}
```

При этом метод `getNextUrl` выглядит примерно так:

```
private String getNextUrl(Call<MessageRs> response, MessageRq rq) throws Exception {
        Response<MessageRs> rs = response.execute();
        rq.setData(...);
        ...
        return rs.body().getLink();
}
```

Я заменила `Call<MessageRs`> на `Observable<MessageRs>` и, как я понимаю, мне нужен метод `flatMap`. А вот как его правильно использовать, я до конца не понимаю...

```
myApi.getFirstCommand(rq)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
       .flatMap(response -> { // как можно передать и response, и rq?
           // и как выполнить это ровно 10 раз?  
           // возможно, после flatMap добавить .forEachWhile(cycle < 10) ?           
           String nextLink = getNextUrl(response, rq);
           myApi.authorize(nextLink, rq);
       })
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(//тут обновляем UI?);
```

Comment: Сложно вам ответить, т.к. не сразу ясно какие запросы и в какой последовательности надо слать. И почему у вас `MessageRq rq` через цепочку запросов меняет внутреннее состояние.

Comment: Плюс не ясно зачем аргументом передавать `Call<MessageRs> response` если его можно прямо в методе, вроде, создавать

Comment: Объясните лучше, зачем вообще это нужно переписывать в RxJava? Зачем монолитную бэкграунд-задачу вы разносите по операторам? flatMap() преобразует один источник в другой, вам, судя по всему, этого не требуется.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно последовательно: 1) отправить запрос на сервер 2) получить некоторую ссылку из ответа сервера 3) Х раз вызвать "авторизоваться, выполнить запрос" ?